# Suppress desktop notifications in fullscreen VLC

Tags: gnome, awesome, vlc, notifications

How to prevent desktop notifications from showing up when VLC is in fullscreen
mode?

Some of my scripts display desktop notifications using `notify-send`. The best
solution would be to configure that `critical` notifications still show up and
`low` prioritised notifications are suppressed. This is how I create the
notifications:

```
notify-send --urgency=low      'Foo' 'Bar'
notify-send --urgency=critical 'Foo' 'Bar'
```

**EDIT:** I am using Gnome version 3.4.2 and awesome WM v3.4.14 on Debian GNU/Linux sid. It does not make a difference if the Gnome `notification-daemon` is started or if awesome is in charge of displaying the notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using:
`notify-send -u low|normal|critical 'Foo' 'Bar'`
could solve your problem...

low and normal shouldn't show up in fullscreen mode, but critical!

EDIT:
looks like it's a bug, which is fixed since version 3.5.3.
see comments for links

Solution:
Update to >3.5.3 or script a little wrapper (grep vlc&fullscreen via xprop and decide if command should go through to notify-send)

Comment: I'm already using `--urgency=low` but notifications still keep showing up.

Comment: before my answer it was `--category`. Anyway. which daemon is running for serving notifications? fallback notification-daemon?

Comment: which os did u use?

Comment: looks like it's a bug, which is fixed since version 3.5.3. [-BUG-](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677590) [-FIX-](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-June/msg01830.html) [-FILE 3.4.2-](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/js/ui/messageTray.js?id=3.4.2#n1457) [-FILE 3.5.3-](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/js/ui/messageTray.js?id=3.5.3#n1457)

Comment: I'm not sure. The bugs you mention are about gnome-shell. I don't use gnome-shell. BTW: The first link is dead. Thanks a lot for investigating!